# Issue of exclamation mark in SAS "Program" tag

Tags: sas

I encountered an issue today with my SAS software. There was an exclamation mark showing on my "Program" tag in parallel to the "Log" tag. I have not seen this before and would appreciate if anyone can tell me what's the problem with my SAS program.

Comment: Did this cause anything to go wrong with your program?  Can you update your question with a screenshot of this 'issue'?

Comment: My reputation is not enough, can not post image, sorry

Comment: which SAS Application are you using?  Web Editor / DI Studio / Base / Enterprise guide?

Answer (score 1):

At least in SAS Enterprise Guide, a yellow triangle with an exclamation mark is a warning symbol. The warning could be negligible, like trying to drop a dataset which do not exist or it could be more serious. The way to find out, is to open your log file and examine the warning.